# Assign to Float from string with precision

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following code, I want to assign a decimal value to float without losing precision.

```
String s1= "525.880005";
Float f = new Float(s1);
System.out.println(f);
```

**Output:**
5.88

**Expected Output:**
525.880005

Comment: What will happen if you use the .parseFloat() - Method?

Comment: @reporter: He effectively is. Both the `Float` constructor and `parseFloat` use the conversion performed by `Float.valueOf(String)`. So it's the same conversion. More: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Float` only has 7-8 significant digits of precision. The "5" in your example is the 9th digit.

Even if it had enough precision, I don't know whether 525.880005 is exactly representable as a binary floating point number. Most decimal values aren't :)

You should use `BigDecimal` if the exact decimal representation is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a real contradiction implied in the question :

> Assign to float <--> wiht precision

525.880005 is jus the number in this float-domain that is closest to 525.88.

The reason that floating numbers cannot be mapped to all numbers is because of **the mismatch between the decimal and the binary system for fractions.**

Other types, such as decimal and money, use other, much more memory consuming, techniques to store the number (for example , in a string you can store any number, but of course this is not the most performant way to do math)

a simple example  : 0.3 in my own binary system :

```
0.1b (inary) would be 0.5 d (ecimal) so too much...
0.01b -->  0.25d (1/4 too little)
0.011 -->  0.375 (1/4 + 1/8 too much)
0.0101 --> 0.3125 (1/4 + 1/16 still too much)
...
0.010011 --> 1/4 +1/32 + 1/64 = 0.296875
```

Suppose my system has 6 bits to represent the fraction, 0.296875 would be the closest for this domain.  The right number cannot be reached due to the decimal/binary system.

For examples see also : 
[Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

And an excellent elaborate explenation of your problems is to be found here: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Another note : it is really about mismatch, not about 'quality' of systems : in decimal notation for example, you cannot represent 1/3 100% accurate, while this would be perfectly possible in other systems.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` type cannot hold every possible value (nor can `double`). If you're assigning from a string, you may prefer [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) as `BigDecimal` can precisely hold anything that you can reasonably represent with a string.

Note that `BigDecimal` *also* cannot hold every possible value (it can't precisely represent 1/3rd, for instance, for the same reason we can't write 1/3rd *precisely* in our decimal notation system — it would never end). But again, if your source is a string value, `BigDecimal` will more closely align with your possible values than will `float` or `double`. Of course, there's a cost. `float` and `double` are designed to be very fast in computation; `BigDecimal` is designed to be very precise with decimal values, at the expense of speed.

Answer (score 0):

`Float` doesn't have enough significant digits to represent your number. Try `Double`.